# What is the simplest way to make scheduled XML parsing into an SQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, xml, cron

So, ok, I'm using PHP for my website, and suppose I know quite a bit of MySQL and a little bit of MS SQL.
Now, I want to parse some XML with PHP/USD exchange rate and store it in the database.

The simplest way one could think of would be, perhaps this:

```
$XMLContent=file("http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=PHP");

foreach($XMLContent as $line){
$a=&strip_tags($line);
if (is_numeric($a))
{
    // output the exchange rate
    echo $a;
    // THen I would probably go like this:
    mssql_query('update table set xchange_rate='.(float)floatval($a));
    // break cycle once found;
    break;
}
}
```

That would perfectly do... if it didn't take 0.8 seconds to run this script, due to external XML GET request.

So I suppose I should use Windows Scheduler, and make a task to run, let's say every hour to update the records. Now the question is, I've no idea what script I would use. I mean, I can't just simply run browser with a PHP script - that would be rediculous.

So, what would be the easiest way to make a script/ application to run it outside PHP, without a need to actually open a browser.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Good point, right now I'm testing it on Win7, but later it is going to be implemented on Windows Server (2008?).

Comment: Have you considered running php from the command line?

Comment: Hmmm, is it ever possible? I never thought of it, I would appreciate if you could give just a little bit more info on that or a direction for a search. Thanks.

Comment: Its definitely possible http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php has a binary executable interpretor too. On win, its called php.exe

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

get it working first from a shell prompt, then make a scheduled task for it.
keep in mind, it is not the same php as you get when running a script through a webserver. Some settings are different, and the version may be different, and may use a different php.ini file(and so may have different extensions loaded).

consider using absolute file paths to start until you get things working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a browser to run a PHP script.  PHP can happily run as a console application.  Without knowing what system you're deploying this on (i.e. which OS), it's hard to give you more directions. For example, on a unix-like system (UN*X, linux, OS X, etc.) you can create your PHP file:

somefile.php

```
<?php

.....

?>
```

save this file into some pre-defined directory, for example, `/opt/myproject` and then schedule it in /etc/crontab (assuming your php is installed in /usr/bin):

```
7 * * * *    /usr/bin/php /opt/myproject/somefile.php
```

This would run your script with PHP, without any browser, once an hour, at 7 minutes past each hour.

**EDIT** If you're to deploy this on a windows server, you can either use `at` command on the command prompt or use the `Task Scheduler` snap-in in `Server Manager` to configure your job.  The PHP script would be saved where you like it to be (e.g. D:\Projects\MyProject\myfile.php) and the command you would schedule to run would be C:\WAMP\bin\php.exe - or whereve your php.exe is located).